# How many N length strings can be made from the alphabet? Need an efficient algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, math

The question is how many strings of length N can be made from the alphabet.

The conditions are:

1. Letters can be repetitive in a string
2. Only letters that are adjacent in the alphabet to a letter can be placed next to each other in the string. for example if N = 4, the strings can be ABCD, ABAB, ABCB, WXYZ, XWXW and so on. They can't be ABCE, CDEG, AAAA as only adjacent letters in the alphabet can be placed next to each other.

I have the answers for N when :

- If N = 3, answer is 98
- If N = 4, answer is 192
- If N = 8, answer is 2896
- If N = 15, answer is 342840
- If N = 30, answer is 9841989098
- If N = 40, answer is 9329564680878

I need to find the answer when N = 50. The algorithm I have made fetches the answer correctly till 30 in 10secs. However, after 30, I think due to the recursive nature of my algorithm, it keeps running and I haven't got an answer.

Here is my java code:

```
class Alphabet {

  public int n;

  public long counter = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Alphabet a = new Alphabet(15);
    a.run();
  }

  public Alphabet(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        this.attach(i, 1);
    }

    System.out.println(this.counter * 2);
  }

  public boolean attach(int letter, int length) {

    if (length == this.n) {
        this.counter++;
        return true;
    }

    if (letter == 0) {
        this.attach(1, length + 1);
        return true;
    }

    if (letter == 25) {
        this.attach(24, length + 1);
        return true;
    }

    this.attach(letter - 1, length + 1);
    this.attach(letter + 1, length + 1);

    return true;
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to get the answer?

Comment: this should be an equation - as opposed to brute force finding all occurrences then counting...

Comment: @Randy If there exists some closed formula for this (probably there is), it is [catalanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) by nature. This formula will be far from trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each letter, calculate the number of strings of length 1 that end in that letter.  For all letters, this is 1.

If you know the number of n-letter strings that end in each letter, then it's easy to calculate the # of n+1 letter strings that end in each letter.  Given your rules, this takes O(alphabet_size) time.  Do this repeatedly until you get to n=N.  Then just add up the counts for all the letters and you're done.

Comment: Very nice answer. [Tried it out](https://ideone.com/SEuG7U) and it calculates fast, e.g. answer for length 300: `2925050770097295459602818153132387445297010628178257678321109580835640669513368151803262738`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot for that :) It is efficient :)

Answer (score 2):

If `x[i][j]` is the number of strings with `j` letters starting with letter `i` (numbered from 0), then `x[i][j]` satisfies these recurrence relations:

```
x[i][1] = 1
x[0][j] = x[1][j-1]
x[25][j] = x[24][j-1]
x[i][j] = x[i-1][j-1] + x[i+1][j-1]
```

That gives you an dynamic-programming style method for solving the problem. (here in Python since it makes the algorithm clearer, but there's no fundamental difficulty in converting it to Java):

```
def strings(n):
    x = [1] * 26
    for _ in xrange(n-1):
        x = [x[1]] + [x[i-1] + x[i+1] for i in xrange(1, 25)] + [x[24]]
    return sum(x)

print strings(40)
```

That is an O(n) (arithmetic operations) solution. It's possible to solve it in O(log n) arithmetic operations by computing the n'th power of a 26x26 matrix.

Let `A` be the matrix `a[i][j]` for `i`,`j`=0..25 where `a[i][j] = 1` if `|i-j]=1` otherwise 0.

Then:

```
x[][j] = A * (x[][j-1])
```

(This is just the recurrence relation written in matrix form).

Then:

```
x[][n] = A^(n-1) (x[][1])
```

Since the matrix power can be computed in O(log n) arithmetic operations (by exponentiation by squaring), once can compute the final `x[][n]` vector in O(log n) time. This in practice doesn't help much since the numbers become large, but if you need to compute the result mod K for some K, then this is an excellent approach.